# Map is not a function when using useState in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have simple application, which requests API in order to retrieve orders.
It is react functional component with typescript.

I just want to display description from all adverts.
I check many tutorials and also threads here and I change state with `useEffect`, which contains function, which request data from API and pass it by `useState`.

At the beginning, I thought that using `useEffect`, useState in parent and passing adverts in props to child  is enough.

Later I did the same in child (`GeneralAdvert.ts`) file, but I still have the same error that:

```
×
TypeError: adverts.map is not a function
GeneralAdvert
D:/reactPhoraTS/reactapp/src/components/Adverts/GeneralAdvert.tsx:19
  16 | });
  17 | 
  18 | 
> 19 | return <div> 
     | ^  20 |   {
  21 |   adverts.map(advert=> (
  22 |     <p key={advert._id}> {advert.desc} </p>
```

Here is parent:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import GeneralAdvert from './components/Adverts/GeneralAdvert';
import FunctionService from './Services/FunctionService';
import Advert from './Entities/Advert';
import IAdvert from './Entities/IAdvert';

const fs = new FunctionService();

function App() {

  let [adverts, setAdverts] = useState<Advert[]>([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAdverts = async () =>{
      const result = await fs.getAdvertAsync();
      console.log(result)
      setAdverts(result);
    }

    fetchAdverts(); 
  },[]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <GeneralAdvert 
      items={adverts}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is child:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Advert from '../../Entities/Advert';
import IAdvert from '../../Entities/IAdvert';

interface IGeneralAdvert {
    items: Array<Advert>
  }
  
  function GeneralAdvert(props:IGeneralAdvert) {

    const [adverts, setAdverts] = useState<Advert[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(props.items)
        setAdverts(props.items);
    });
    
    
    return <div> 
      {
      adverts.map(advert=> (
        <p key={advert._id}> {advert.desc} </p>
      ))} 
    </div> 

      //tried at the beggining with using just props.items 
      //and without setAdvert in useEffet() here, but he same outcome
      // <div>
      // {props.items.map(x => <h2>{x.desc}</h2>)}
      // </div> 

  }

  export default GeneralAdvert;
```

Here is simple function:

```
async getAdvertAsync(): Promise<Advert[]> {
   let q: Advert[];
        
    let x = await this.syncService.apiAsync<Advert>("http://localhost:7071/api/getPerson");
    q = x;

    return q;
}
```

From console.log:

[image: Here is also information from logs]

Comment: I think you have to do  `adverts.items.map` because  `result` is a dictionary `{item: array}`, so you want to access the array (value) of the dictionary

Comment: Yes, you right. I added such thing in internal function: await response.json().then(data => data.items) and it worked. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to do `adverts.items.map` because `result` is an object `{item: array}`, so you want to access the array (value) of the object.

You can either:

```
adverts.items.map
```

or

```
setAdverts(result.items)
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your `result` stores an object, not an array, which is causing the error. Looking at the log, it looks like you want to use `result.items` instead of `result`

So changing this

```
const result = await fs.getAdvertAsync();
console.log(result)
setAdverts(result);
```

to this

```
const result = await fs.getAdvertAsync();
console.log(result)
setAdverts(result.items); // Access the `items` property
```

should fix the error